# Java spring map can not infer type-variable R

Tags: java, spring, java-stream

I've searched for a lot of time and I cannot find a way to solve this problem. In my spring application I have a `BesoinPoseMapper`

```
@FunctionalInterface
@Mapper(uses = BesoinPoseTranslator.class)
public interface BesoinPoseMapper {
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "nbCapteurs", source = "valeur", qualifiedByName = {"BesoinPoseTranslator", "nbCapteurs"}),
            @Mapping(target = "typologie", source = "typologie", qualifiedByName = {"BesoinPoseTranslator", "typologie"}),
            @Mapping(target = "site", source = "site", qualifiedByName = {"BesoinPoseTranslator", "emplacement"})
    })
    BesoinPoseDTO entityToDTO(BesoinPoseEntity entity);
}
```

To map the `BesoinPoseEntity` into `BesoinPoseDTO`

However the map function in `BesoinPoseController`

```
public class BesoinPoseController {

    @Setter
    @Autowired
    private BesoinPoseRepository besoinPoseRepo;

    @GetMapping()
    public List<BesoinPoseDTO> getBesoinsPose(@RequestParam String range, @RequestParam(required = false) String status){

        return StreamSupport.stream(besoinPoseRepo.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                .map(BesoinPoseMapper::entityToDTO)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

throws a compilation error

```
                .map(BesoinPoseMapper::entityToDTO);
                ^
  required: Function<? super BesoinPoseEntity,? extends R>
  found: BesoinPose[...]ToDTO
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
    (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
      cannot find symbol
        symbol:   method entityToDTO(BesoinPoseEntity)
        location: interface BesoinPoseMapper)
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream
```

I've tried using lambdas and changing types from iterable to list and arrays and back to streams but to no avail, the error persists. The compiler cannot infer that the R type is `BesoinPoseDTO` .

Is there anyway to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need an Instance of `BesoinPoseMapper` [read this](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-composition)

Comment: When you use `.map(BesoinPoseMapper::entityToDTO)`, the compiler will try to find `entityToDTO()` on the type of your stream elements (which in this case will only work if `besoinPoseRepo.findAll()` returns objects of a type that is a subclass of `BesoinPoseMapper` - unless `BesoinPoseMapper.entityToDTO` is static. Clearly, this is not the case. As YCF_L said, you probably meant to have an instance of `BesoinPoseMapper` and use `.map(myBesoinPoseMapperInstance::entityToDTO)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `BesoinPoseMapper` in another word an entry point to the instance once the implementation of your mapper is generated like this:

```
@Mapper(uses = BesoinPoseTranslator.class)
public interface BesoinPoseMapper {
    BesoinPoseMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BesoinPoseMapper.class);
    //...
}
```

Now in your component you can use:

```
.map(BesoinPoseMapper.INSTANCE::entityToDTO);
```

or :

```
private BesoinPoseMapper besoinPoseMapper = BesoinPoseMapper.INSTANCE;

...

.map(besoinPoseMapper::entityToDTO);
```

---

#### Spring

Or because you are using spring you can use `componentModel = "spring"`:

```
@Mapper(uses = BesoinPoseTranslator.class, componentModel = "spring")
```

and then you can inject your mapper in your component as any spring component for example:

```
@Autowired
private BesoinPoseMapper besoinPoseMapper;
```

---

- [3.2. Mapping Composition (experimental)](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-composition)
- [4.2. Using dependency injection](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#using-dependency-injection)

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I try the first solution, I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find implementation for models.mappers.BesoinPoseMapper`
and when I try the second, the compiler tells me to `Consider defining a bean of type BesoinPoseMapper`
Am I doing something wrong again ?

Comment: @ErgiS it seems you are missing to clean install your code, to generate the Implementation of your mapper

Comment: Did a gradle clean and the error is still there. When the `.INSTANCE` is used I have the `Cannot find implementation` error and when a private field is used I hava the `Consider defining a bean`

Comment: @ErgiS did you read the example here https://mapstruct.org/

Comment: @ErgiS there are a full list of [example here](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/4aed56993f8dd1e1ec77e4bfacf2f9422195ed57)

Comment: Yeah I needed to add the dependency inside the build.gradle . It works now. I am having the same problem with unit testing where the mapper bean is not defined, it must be a gradle dependency here too.
Thanks a lot for the help